# matplotlib.pyplot.figure.number => always 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) and it says this about the number of the object:

> **matplotlib.pyplot.figure(num=None)**
>
> num: numint or str, optional, default: None
>
> If not provided, a new figure will be created, and the figure number will be incremented. The figure objects holds this number in a number attribute. If num is provided, and a figure with this id already exists, make it active, and returns a reference to it. If this figure does not exists, create it and returns it. If num is a string, the window title will be set to this figure's num.

As a result, I would expect as I create new figures within the session and then get the Number attribute,

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figure.number
```

will be incrementing. So for my second figure I would expect the value of the number attribute to be 2. However, I seem to be getting 1 for the number attribute no matter what (unless I assign num=x myself, but that is not my question):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
figure1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], "r")
print(figure1.number)
>>> 1
```

```
figure2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], "g")
print(figure2.number)
>>> 1
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you closing the figure in between each call?

If I'm creating two figures without closing the window, then the numbers are 1 and 2 as expected.

However, if I'm creating figure no 1. then closing the plot window, and then creating `figure2`, then `figure2.number == 1`.

It appears that pyplot keeps track of the figures that are open and assigns new numbers only if an opened figure has already the same number

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I leave the figures open, then consecutive numbers are assigned. I marked the answer as correct.